# R: How to calculate the differences in two tables for two different years

Tags: r

i'm writing an R script in order to automatically check columns in large tables according to the development over time. i have two tables (for two years) with abouth 3000 rows (slightly different in both years) and 450 columns (the same in both years). what i want to do is i want to calculate the difference (rom 2014 to 2015) between the values in each column for the same id. unfortunately, the number of ids is not the same for both years and neither is the order. the approach i used is only working, if the number and order in the two tables is the same. please find below a short example:

```
>     id <- c('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4')
>     year <- c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)
>     numbers <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
>     table1 <- data.frame(id, year, numbers)
> 
>     id <- c('a2', 'a3', 'a4')
>     year <- c(2015, 2015, 2015)
>     numbers <- c(100, 200, 300)
>     table2 <- data.frame(id, year, numbers)
>
```

i want all ids of observations, which have a higher value in 2014 in a
separate table3:

> ```
> > table3 <- as.data.frame(which(table2[,3] - table1[,3])<0)
> ```
>
> of course, this can't work, but i'm not coming to the solution. i
>   would be glad, if anyone could help me out. thanks in advance!

EDIT: thank you for all the suggestions. unfortunately, i have to us R
version 2.13, since i use sweave to create a report at the end and
newer versions have problems with codings. thus, dplyr is not working
(version 3.0.2). i will provide an extended example in order to
illustrate my problem a bit better:

```
> id <- c('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4')
> year <- c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)
> numbers1 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers2 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers3 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers4 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers5 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers6 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers7 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers8 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers9 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> numbers10 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
> table1 <- data.frame(id, year, numbers1, numbers2, numbers3, numbers4, numbers5, numbers6, numbers7,numbers8, numbers9, numbers10)
> id <- c('a2', 'a3', 'a4') year <- c(2015, 2015, 2015)
> numbers1 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers2 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers3 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers4 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers5 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers6 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers7 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers8 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers9 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> numbers10 <- c(100, 200, 300)
> table2 <- data.frame(id, year, numbers1, numbers2, numbers3, numbers4, numbers5, numbers6, numbers7,numbers8, numbers9, numbers10)
```

at the end of the day, i want to compare numbers from the same columns with same ids. any suggestions are highly welcome, i am stuck for days now...
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the data, and then use `filter` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
merge(table1, table2, by = 'id') %>% filter(numbers.x > numbers.y)
  id year.x numbers.x year.y numbers.y
1 a2   2014       200   2015       100
2 a3   2014       300   2015       200
3 a4   2014       400   2015       300
```

---

For your larger example, I would also use the `gather` function from `tidyr` to change the formatting of the code:

```
merge(table1 %>% gather(key, value, -id, -year), 
      table2 %>% gather(key, value, -id, -year), 
      by = c('id', 'key')) %>% 
  filter(value.x > value.y)
```

Which yields the following output (shown are the first 6 rows):

```
  id       key year.x value.x year.y value.y
1 a2  numbers1   2014     200   2015     100
2 a2 numbers10   2014     200   2015     100
3 a2  numbers2   2014     200   2015     100
4 a2  numbers3   2014     200   2015     100
5 a2  numbers4   2014     200   2015     100
6 a2  numbers5   2014     200   2015     100
```

So it scales to any number of `numbers` columns easily.

Comment: Can this be scaled? Because OP mentioned 450 columns.

Comment: It probably can, a more comprehensive example would be benefial here @Daniel W-s

Comment: hi, i added an extended example. is this helpful?

Comment: @DanielW-s I added some code that works on your example, which shows you can efficiently handle multiple `numbers` columns.

Comment: @Paul thank you for your answer. unfortunately, i have to use R 2.13, which does not support tidyr and dplyr. do you have any idea without using those packages? also, i actually don't know what %>% means. could you help me out?

Comment: I would not know how to take this approach in base R, so I don't really think I can help you any further. Another package that can do similar things is `reshape2`, althought this might also not be available for R v02.13. I would really recommend you change your reporting to using `knitr`. This is a better package, which vastly improves upon `Sweave`. In addition this would allow you to switch away from your ancient version of R.

Comment: @Paul thanks for all your efforts to solve my problem!

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` variation

```
dta = rbind(table1, table2)

library(dplyr)

dta %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(cond = ifelse(numbers [year == 2014] > numbers[year == 2015], numbers, 0)) %>% 
  filter(cond != 0)
```